# Primefaces showMessageInDialog close automatically after 3 secs

Tags: primefaces

We are using PrimeFaces 5. We are displaying messages in dialog box using:

```java
RequestContext.getCurrentInstance().showMessageInDialog(new FacesMessage("This is a message"));
```

After displaying this dialog we want the dialog to get closed automatically after 3 secs. How to achieve this ?

Answer (score 1):

After you call `showMessageInDialog` from the `RequestContext` execute a hide on the current opened message (which is `PrimeFaces.dialog.DialogHandler.messageDialog`) after a certain milliseconds

So the full call would be

```java
RequestContext.getCurrentInstance().showMessageInDialog(new FacesMessage("This is a message"));

RequestContext.getCurrentInstance().execute("
    setTimeout(function({PrimeFaces.dialog.DialogHandler.messageDialog.hide()}
    ,3000)");// 3 seconds
```

*note 1000 ms = 1 second*

Answer (score 0):

A naive solution, but it could work:

```java
RequestContext.getCurrentInstance().showMessageInDialog(new FacesMessage());
new Thread(new Runnable() { 
    public void run() {
        Thread.sleep(3000);
        //close dialog here
    }
}).start();
```

Comment: How would you close the dialog ?